# Matlab: Are local functions (subfunctions) compiled together with main function or separately?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have heard that MATLAB has an automatic in-need compilation of functions which could create a lot of function-call overhead if you call a function many times like in the following code:

```
function output = BigFunction( args )
    for i = 1:10000000
        SmallFunction( args );
    end
end
```

Is it faster to call the function `SmallFunction()` if I put it in the same file as `BigFunction()` as a local function? Or is there any good solution other than pasting the code from `SmallFunction()` into the `BigFunction()` to optimize the performance?

Edit: It may be false assumption that the function-call overhead is because of the in-need compilation. The question is how to cut down on the overhead without making the code look awful.

Comment: Even though its interesting to know there are differences, I highly doubt you will get a significant speedup from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my first question is that a local function performs the same as a function in another file.

An idea for the second question is to, if possible, make `SmallFunction()` an inline-function, which has less function-call overhead. I found more about function-call performances in the [MathWorks forum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99537-which-type-of-function-call-provides-better-performance-in-matlab), and I paste the question and answer below:

Question:

> I have 7 different types of function call:
>
> 1. An Inline function. The body of the function is directory written down (inline).
> 2. A function is defined in a separate MATLAB file. The arguments are passed by the calling function (file-pass).
> 3. A function is defined in a separate MATLAB file. The arguments are provided by referencing global variables; only indices are provided by the calling function (file-global).
> 4. A nested function. The arguments are passed by the enclosing function (nest-pass).
> 5. A nested function. The arguments are those shared with the enclosing function; only indices are provided by the enclosing function (nest-share).
> 6. A sub function. The arguments are passed by the calling function (sub-pass).
> 7. A sub function. The arguments are provided by referencing global variables; only indices are provided by the calling function (sub-global).
>
> I would like to know which function call provides better performance than the others in general.

The answer from MathWorks Support Team pasted here:

> The ordering of performance of each function call from the fastest to the  slowest tends to be as follows:
>
> inline > file-pass = nest-pass = sub-pass > nest-share > sub-global > file-global
>
> (A>B means A is faster than B and A=B means A is as fast as B)
>
> First, inline is the fastest as it does not incur overhead associated with  function call.
>
> Second, when the arguments are passed to the callee function, the calling function sets up the arguments in such a way that the callee function knows where to retrieve them. This setup associated with function call in general incurs performance overhead, and therefore file-pass, nest-pass, and sub-pass are slower than inline.
>
> Third, if the workspace is shared with nested functions and the arguments to a nested function are those shared within the workspace, rather than pass-by-value, then performance of that function call is inhibited. If MATLAB sees a shared variable within the shared workspace, it searches the workspace for the variable. On the other hand, if the arguments are passed by the calling function, then MATLAB does not have to search for them. The time taken for this search explains that type nest-share is slower than file-pass, nest-pass, and sub-pass.
>
> Finally, when a function call involves global variables, performance is even more inhibited. This is because to look for global variables, MATLAB has to expand its search space to the outside of the current workspace. Furthermore, the reason a function call involving global variables appears a lot slower than the others is that MATLAB Accelerator does not optimize such a function call. When MATLAB Accelerator is turned off with the following command,
>
> feature accel off
>   the difference in performance between inline and file-global becomes less significant.
>
> Please note that the behaviors depend largely on various factors such as operating systems, CPU architectures, MATLAB Interpreter, and what the MATLAB  code is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "inline function"? An anonymous function? These usually are slightly less performant than an equivalent sub-function or M-file function in my experience. Or do you mean doing the inlining yourself, i.e., not actually a function!?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the ambiguity in "inline function". What I meant was an anonymous function defined with syntax: `sqr = @(x) x.^2;`. I do not agree with you with the performance though. I made a quick performance test with comparing the performance of having the square-function as an anonymous function as above or having it in a separate file and doing the operation a great number of time. The anonymous function performs significantly better, but pasting the code performs even better.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab hashes the functions it reads into memory.  The functions are only compiled once if they exist as an independent function in its own file.  If you put `BigFunction` in `BigFunction.m` and `SmallFunction` in `SmallFunction.m` then you should recieve the optimization benefit of having the m-script compiled once.